# How can I calculate the cost of enhanced monitoring on a particular RDS Instance.

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, amazon-rds

I want to setup enhanced monitoring on one of our RDS instances. But I am not able to calculate the cost it will incur every month.

I checked the aws doc at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Monitoring.OS.html and it says it depends on the several factors, one of them being logs which are free for upto 5gb per month under free tier(the free tier is only for the initial one year and these 5gb will not be applicable for the older aws accounts if am right).  Rest 3 somehow seems to again related to writing logs.

Please help me on how I can calculate the cost incurred only due to enabling of enhanced monitoring on an AWS RDS instance.

--Junaid.

Comment: You might want to ask AWS directly about this, as their engineers are more knowledgeable than most folks on Stack Overflow.  If you can do a back-of-the-envelope calculation and conclude that it should not cost too much, then try it out for one billing month and see what the actual cost is.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

RDS's enhanced monitoring cost is just CloudWatch cost

One of the biggest part of CW cost is the total amount of logs you write in Bytes which is about $0.50/GB ( varies in different regions )

Back on to the question, you can approximate the cost incur by just enabling detailed monitoring, I suggest start with one minute granularity. After a few hour, you will have some logs appear in your CW logs. You can [get the total amount of data ingestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43327714/my-aws-cloudwatch-bill-is-huge-how-do-i-work-out-which-log-stream-is-causing-it) and estimate from there

Personally, logging at 1 minute interval for a single RDS DB cost me close to $0.00

Comment: Using Multi-AZ MySQL on RDS, I'm doing 15s interval enhanced monitoring on a t3.large and I'm seeing just under 140 MB/day of CloudWatch data ingestion. That comes to 4.1 GB/month, or $2.10 per month for enhanced monitoring.