# How do I get a sum of megabytes sent to a set of Cloudwatch log groups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

I need to get a sum of MB sent to a bunch of Cloudwatch log groups as data, not in the console. But first I need to get sums for two working.

I started with an [AWS support article.](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudwatch-logs-bill-increase/) Then I grabbed the metric names I needed from the Cloudwatch console. Then looked at the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/get-metric-data.html) for the `get-metric-data` CLI.

[image: cloudwatch metrics groups]

Between the three this was the closest I got:

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-data --profile default --metric-data-queries file://./.temp/metric-data-queries.json  \
--start-time 2019-12-04T00:00:00Z --end-time 2019-12-18T00:00:00Z
```

Where the query file looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "mbSum",
        "MetricStat": {
            "Metric": {
                "Namespace": "AWS/Logs",
                "MetricName": "IncomingBytes",
                "Dimensions": [
                    {
                        "Name": "LogGroupName",
                        "Value": "/aws/lambda/prd-***-lambda"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "LogGroupName",
                        "Value": "/aws/lambda/prd-****-lambda"
                    }
                    ... 98 more, down the road, but just two for now
                ]
            },
            "Period": 1209600,
            "Stat": "Sum",
            "Unit": "Megabytes"
        }
    }
]
```

The result I got was:

```
{
    "MetricDataResults": [
        {
            "Id": "mbSum",
            "Label": "IncomingBytes",
            "Timestamps": [],
            "Values": [],
            "StatusCode": "Complete"
        }
    ],
    "Messages": []
}
```

I'd expect a zero in there if there were no results. Tried with a period of 300 (like the `get-metric-data` doc suggests), no change. The information I have regarding period is contradictory/unclear. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting this working with the AWS CLI was a huge hassle. Ended up grabbing a Python script [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52223135/30946) and modifying it a little:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Outputs all loggroups with > 1GB of incomingBytes in the past x days

import boto3
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta

days_to_check=30

logs_client = boto3.client('logs')
boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name="default")
cloudwatch_client = boto3.client('cloudwatch')

end_date = dt.today().isoformat(timespec='seconds')
start_date = (dt.today() - timedelta(days=days_to_check)).isoformat(timespec='seconds')
print("looking from %s to %s" % (start_date, end_date))

paginator = logs_client.get_paginator('describe_log_groups')
pages = paginator.paginate()
page_c = 0
total_checked = 0

for page in pages:
  page_c += 1
  for json_data in page['logGroups']:
    total_checked += 1
    log_group_name = json_data.get("logGroupName")

    print(f"Page {page_c}: checking {log_group_name}                                    ", end="\r", flush=True)

    cw_response = cloudwatch_client.get_metric_statistics(
       Namespace='AWS/Logs',
       MetricName='IncomingBytes',
       Dimensions=[
        {
            'Name': 'LogGroupName',
            'Value': log_group_name
        },
        ],
        StartTime= start_date,
        EndTime=end_date,
        Period=3600 * 24 * days_to_check,
        Statistics=[
            'Sum'
        ],
        Unit='Bytes'
    )
    if len(cw_response.get("Datapoints")):
        stats_data = cw_response.get("Datapoints")[0]
        stats_sum = stats_data.get("Sum")
        sum_GB = stats_sum /  (1000 * 1000 * 1000)
        if sum_GB > 1.0:
            print("   **** %s exceeded 1GB log sent, total %.2f GB **** " % (log_group_name , sum_GB))

print(f"Done. Checked {total_checked} logs.                                         ")
```

Worth noting that we have 1000s of log groups, so the CLI was going to be a difficult solution for this. If anyone wants to improve that, go for it. My python is meh.

Comment: Script is very useful, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

These metrics are emitted with unit `Bytes` and CloudWatch is not doing any conversion on the unit automatically. Change the unit to `Bytes` (or don't specify the unit at all) and use metric math to convert bytes to megabytes.

Here is a simplified request that sums up all the incoming bytes for all log groups:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "mbSum",
        "Expression": "SUM(SEARCH('{AWS/Logs,LogGroupName} MetricName=\"IncomingBytes\"', 'Sum', 1209600))/1000000",
        "ReturnData": true
    }
]
```

Response I got on my test account:

```
{
    "MetricDataResults": [
        {
            "Timestamps": [
                "2019-12-04T00:00:00Z"
            ],
            "StatusCode": "Complete",
            "Values": [
                4.844451
            ],
            "Id": "mbSum",
            "Label": "mbSum"
        }
    ] }
```

Saved the payload in `query.json` and executed this command:

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-data --metric-data-queries file://query.json  \
--start-time 2019-12-04T00:00:00Z --end-time 2019-12-18T00:00:00Z
```

Comment: You sure? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/get-metric-data.html disagrees with this. Changed it to Bytes, no difference.

Comment: Yeah, from the doc you linked: 'If you specify a unit, the operation returns only data data that was collected with that unit specified. If you specify a unit that does not match the data collected, the results of the operation are null. CloudWatch does not perform unit conversions'.

Comment: Next thing to check would be region and creds. Make sure the region in the default profile matches the one where the metrics are and the creds match the account.

Comment: OK but I changed it to Bytes and still got an empty result set. Same result for no units specified.

Comment: Tried adding `--region us-west-2` (and the the other 3 US regions) to the CLI call -- no change in result.

Comment: I updated the answer with a request that I tested on my account, to rule out any issue with the request payload.

Comment: Ah, I see, you listed all the dimensions under the same metric. Those should be separate metrics. See if my SEARCH expression works for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204504/discussion-between-jcollum-and-unkindness-of-datapoints).